# If I underwent baptism when I was an adult, but If now I am no longer certain that Jesus revived, then am I still a Christian?

Tags: baptism, faith, resurrection-of-jesus, historical-jesus, christian-identity

When I was in my 20s, I was baptised.

Now I am my 30s, and I am no longer certain that Jesus revived.

---

**(Positive)** The following is a reason that I can believe that Jesus had revived:

In Bible, his disciples ran away before Jesus died. However, although we don't know that Jesus really had revived historically, according to the Bible the disciples of Jesus changed from *'running away from Jesus'* to *'following the way Jesus taught'*.

The change in his disciples is one reason that I think Jesus had revived. If Jesus had not revived, then in my opinion his disciples would not have changed.

---

**(Negative)** However I also think that I am not sure that Jesus revived:

Because every person died, and there is no person in history that revived after dying of suffocation.

---

Am I still a Christian?

Comment: In general, if you say you are a christian, you are. Different churches may have different views on it, but as a general rule, nobody can decide for you what you are or are not.

But if I may, I think your question holds three possible questions:
1. What is the definition  of a christian?
2. What to believe about the resurrection of Christ?
3. What is exactly the meaning of baptism?

If I am correct, you may want to specify your question a bit more. If not, I am sorry.

Comment: This question is off-topic. The site deliberately accepts all _self-identifying_ 'Christians' as Christian. Therefore it is not within the scope of the site to determine who are and who are not 'Christians'. They decide that for themselves by identifying themselves as such.

Comment: You are asking very subjective question that can only elicit opinions as a response. While we could discuss the meaning of 'Christian' or whether baptism is sufficient grounds to make one a Christian -- or even whether believing acceptance of the resurrection is sufficient grounds to call oneself a Christian -- these topics rely completely upon one's doctrines and definitions.

Comment: Your negative reason depends on the premise that Miracles can't happen. If God exists and is capable of acting outside of the normal laws of nature (which are God's doing as well!), then there is no reason to reject the possibility that Christ rose from the dead. The rise of Christianity is good evidence that this in fact happened. The existence of life is excellent evidence that something Created it. Viewed from the proper perspective, other evidence overwhelmingly points toward Genesis 1-11 being accurate history. All reasons to deny God rest on... denying God.

Comment: I agree with others that this isn't really a suitable question for this site. You really should speak to a pastor. However, we'd also be happy to talk with you in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being baptised does not make a person a Christian.  Having faith in the Son of God, the resurrected and glorified Christ, is essential if you are to call yourself a Christian.

If Jesus was not resurrected after his crucifixion, did not ascended into heaven from whence he came, and is not sitting at the right hand side of God, then there is no basis for Christianity.

There are several compelling lines of historical evidence for the resurrection of Jesus:

> The demonstrable sincerity of the eyewitnesses (and in the Apostles’ case, compelling, inexplicable change).

> The conversion and demonstrable sincerity of key antagonists, and skeptics-turned-martyrs.

> The fact of the empty tomb, enemy attestation to the empty tomb, the fact that all of this took place in Jerusalem where faith in the resurrection began and thrived.

> The testimony of the women, the significance of such testimony given the historical context.

These all attest to the historicity of the resurrection. Please note, resurrection from the dead, not that Jesus "revived".  Please read this article: https://www.gotquestions.org/why-believe-resurrection.html

Doubt and lack of faith can be rectified by a heartfelt desire to learn more about Christ Jesus and what God has done, through him, to save us from the consequences of our sinful nature. Pick up your Bible and read the gospel of John.

Like the disciples who ran away, you can still turn round and follow Him.